# Error en tkinter, mi variable no esta definida "Quit button is not defined"

Tags: python, tkinter, game

codigo

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
tk=Tk()
tk.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
global PlayButton
global OptionsButton
global QuitButton
class Buttons:
   def WriteTXT():None
   def PlayButton():None
   def OptionsButton():
       PlayButton.pack_forget()
       QuitButton.pack_forget()
       OptionsButton.pack_forget()
   def QuitButton():
       tk.destroy()

ButtonFont=("Calibri",36)
PlayButton=Button(tk,text="Jugar",command=Buttons.PlayButton())
PlayButton.pack()
OptionsButton=Button(tk,text="Opciones",command=Buttons.OptionsButton())
OptionsButton.pack()
QuitButton=Button(tk,text="Cerrar",command=Buttons.QuitButton)
QuitButton.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

mi error es el siguiente

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> "h:\bind.d\apps\enproceso\game_peter_main_.py", line 21, in 
> OptionsButton=Button(tk,text="Opciones",command=Buttons.OptionsButton())
> File "h:\bind.d\apps\enproceso\game_peter_main_.py", line 13, in
> OptionsButton    QuitButton.pack_forget() NameError: name 'QuitButton'
> is not defined

Comment: Cuando colocas parentesis a la derecha de una funcion, la estas ejecutando. Para que no se ejecute, quita los parentesis.

Comment: Hola, te entendi, ya lo hice y me funciono